# how to modify class and its methods to let me call necessary method of another class?

Tags: c++

```
class A  {
private:
    char a;
    char sub_f(char *);
public:
    A();
    char f(char* ) {some actions using sub_f(char*);}  
};

class B {
private:
    char b;
public:
    B();
    void execute() { b = f("some text");}  //PROBLEM IS HERE
}
```

Can smb explain me how can I call `f(char *)` function which is a member of class A, from the `void B::execute()` ? I can't compile it right now. If I make `f(char*)` a friend function of the class A, there is another problem appear :
`friend f(char*)`  doesn't know anything about private function `sub_f(char*)` .
I am a beginner in C++ and will be appreciate for full answers with explanation.

Comment: `'some text'` is not the correct syntax for a string literal (you need double quotes `"some text"`). Also it is incorrect to pass around string literals as `char*`, you should at least use `const char*` or preferably `std::string`

Comment: To call a (non-`static`) method of another class you need an *instance* of that class first

Comment: ok, let it be double quotes. But the problem is about how to call `f()` function from execute one?

Comment: Please read a good C++ book, here's a list of recommended ones: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list

Answer (score 0):

If you have a public member function, like

```
class A  {
public:
    char f(char* );// {some actions using sub_f(char*);}  
};
```

you can call it on an instance

```
A a;
char just_one_char = a.f("Whatever");
```

The same applies across the board - to call this member function you need an instance.

One approach would be to make your class `B` have a member variable of type `A`:

```
class B {
private:
    char b;
    a a;
public:
    B();
    void execute() { b = a.f("some text");}  //PROBLEM Solved
};
```

If `f` doesn't need any instance data from class `A` it could be static, or a free function.

Perhaps there isn't a one-to-one relationship between B and A like this.
Perhaps execute could make an A when it needed to:

```
class B {
private:
    char b;
public:
    B();
    void execute() {
        A a;//just needed for this function call, rather than lifetime of B
        b = a.f("some text");  //PROBLEM is solved a different way
   }
};
```